# I want to make an if statement that each image would be full screen when the user is tap

Tags: swift, image

here is the code that I check if they images are tapped but only the 3 image is apply full screen. As you can see I set the image is tapped to statusImageView to call the function of zoomImage So I want fixed for all images.

```
func imageTapped() {
  let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer:)))

    if detailsImage[0].tag == 0 {
        detailsImage[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        detailsImage[0].addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.statusImageView = detailsImage[0]
    }
    let tapGestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        detailsImage[1].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        detailsImage[1].addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer1)
        self.statusImageView = detailsImage[1]
    
    let tapGestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        detailsImage[2].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        detailsImage[2].addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer2)
        self.statusImageView = detailsImage[2]
 
}



let blackBackgroundColor = UIView()
let tappedImage = UIImageView()
var statusImageView: UIImageView?
let navigationBarView = UIView()


@objc func imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    annimationImage(detailsImage: statusImageView!)
}
```

And then I call the annihilationImage function which is takes the statusImageView as input

```
    func annimationImage(detailsImage: UIImageView) {
    
    if let startingFrame = statusImageView?.superview?.convert(statusImageView!.frame, to: nil) {
        
        statusImageView!.alpha =  0
        
    blackBackgroundColor.frame = self.view.frame
    blackBackgroundColor.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    blackBackgroundColor.alpha = 0
    view.addSubview(blackBackgroundColor)
        
        navigationBarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 100)
        navigationBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        navigationBarView.alpha = 0
        
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            keyWindow.addSubview(navigationBarView)
        }

    let tappedImage = UIImageView()
    tappedImage.backgroundColor = .gray
    tappedImage.frame = startingFrame
    tappedImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    tappedImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tappedImage.image = statusImageView?.image
    tappedImage.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(tappedImage)
      
       
   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, animations: {
        tappedImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300)

        })
    }
}
```

I want to make an if statement that while check which image is tapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tapGestureRecognizer.view` for getting a view that is assigned a tap gesture. And by this, you can also get the view tag (your view is corresponding to the image view in your code)

```
@objc func imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let senderView = tapGestureRecognizer.view // Here you get a view that is associated with the gesture
    let tag = senderView?.tag // Here you get a tag that is assigned to all image

// Add your condition here by tag 

 annimationImage(detailsImage: statusImageView!)
}
```